# How to get the index of the tickmarks of an input type=range?

Tags: javascript, html, input-type-range

I am having a input `type=range` and need to know which tickmark index my slider has to get some values out of an array.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange"); 
var output = document.getElementById("output"); 
var repaymentsInfo = document.getElementById("repayments"); 
var requiredIncome = document.getElementById("income"); 
var ticks = document.getElementsByTagName("option");


var repayList = [];
var incomeList = [];


for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++){
    repayList.push(data[i].repaymentsPerMonth)
    incomeList.push(data[i].requiredAnnualIncome)
}

slider.oninput = function(){
output.innerHTML = this.value;
repaymentsInfo.innerHTML = repayList[**index**];
requiredIncome.innerHTML = incomeList[**index**];
};
slider.oninput();`
```

I tried all the possible attributes of `slider.oninput`, but I can't find the solution how to extract the current index of my slider point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can calculate it. Try running the snippit - it shows how.
if you wanna fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Phiddle/z0xw2eoL/54/

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var index = document.getElementById("index");
var tickIndex = document.getElementById("tickIndex");
var tickValue = document.getElementById("tickValue");

var ticks = ['First', 'Huhu', 'Jaja', 'Gugu', 'Yoooo', 'Last'];

const steps = 17;
const amountEachStep = 150000;
const maxValue = amountEachStep*steps;
const amountPerTick= maxValue/(ticks.length-1)

slider.max = maxValue;
slider.step = amountEachStep;

slider.oninput = function(){
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  index.innerHTML = this.value/this.step;
  tickIndex.innerHTML = Math.round(this.value/amountPerTick);
  tickValue.innerHTML = ticks[Math.round(this.value/amountPerTick)];
};
slider.oninput();
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input id="myRange" type="range" />
<div>Value:</div>
<div id="output"></div>
<div>Step:</div>
<div id="index"></div>
<div>Tick Index:</div>
<div id="tickIndex"></div>
<div>Tick Value:</div>
<div id="tickValue"></div>
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this is unfortunately not possible because my steps are not the same amount as the number of entries. My steps are 150.000 and my amount of steps jist 17. Any work around?

Comment: What would a, b and c your input be? 

<input type="range" min="a" max="b" step=c"" />

Comment: Updated the answer to calculate the max-value of the slider from steps*amountEachStep - if this does not help please answere my question in the comment above. 

Cheers
Phil

Answer (score 0):

```js
slider.oninput = function() {
  const i = data.findIndex(({ propertyValue }) => propertyValue == this.value);
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  repaymentsInfo.innerHTML = repayList[I]
  requiredIncome.innerHTML = incomeList[i]
};
slider.oninput()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: does this `data` have 17 elements and `this.value` to be in range of `0..150,000` as you commented above?